# VBA/Excel - Array to non contiguous range

Tags: excel, vba

Con el objetivo de rellenar un rango de celdas desde un array, me gustaría preguntaros si es posible hacerlo en rangos no contiguos, es decir insertando los valores en áreas determinadas sin eliminar el contenido de las celdas intermedias.

Ejemplo:

[image]

Lo que busco es hacer una asignación tipo:

```
range ("A1:E4") = MyArray
```

...sin modificar las celdas en amarillo marcadas como "dummy".

Gracias de antemano,
av9

Comment: No, no se puede. Cuando vuelcas el array se vuelca entero. Quizás con un loop podrías evitar volcar todo pero ya sería haciendo un bucle.

Comment: Primero para hacer una referencia sin las columnas «dummy», debes escribir `Range("A1:A4,E1:E4")`; `,` se llama el operador de unión de referencias. Luego debes explicar qué es exactamente `MyArray` (puede ser un `Array` VBA; o una matriz Excel, de formula `{1\5;2\6;3\7;4\8}`; o el contenido del portapapeles en forma de tabla). Finalmente no creo qué se puede asignar en una sola instrucción a una `Range` de más de una `Área`s; hay que pasar por un bucle `For`/`Next`, excepto si pasa por el portapapeles (en cuyo caso hay que amagar las columnas intermediarias).

Comment: Gracias Antoine. MyArray is un array VBA de tipo "Variant" el cual redimensiono al tamaño del rango definido en la hoja de Excel. La solución mas obvia y sencilla es hacer algo como:

MyArray = range ("A1:E4")
...actualizar las celdas de interés en MyArray...
range ("A1:E4") = MyArray

De esta manera se evitan bucles de acceso a "Cells" y se acelera el proceso de escritura en múltiples celdas. Mi pregunta era si había otra manera de hacer lo mismo con rangos no contiguos usando concatenaciones de areas o uniones, por si hay celdas que no quieres tocar de ninguna de las maneras.